# Use Up and Down Arrow to Navigate Extjs Tree

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have an extjs tree panel (Ext.tree.Panel). I want to use up and down arrow to navigate the items and trigger the item click event.

Let me know how I could do this.

Thanks,

Comment: Key navigation is already built in to the tree. Your question isn't clear.

Comment: Hi Evan - in the tree when I click up and down arrow, the selection changes. But the itemclick event is not triggered. What I want is, when we press up/down button, we change the selected and automatically trigger itemclick event for it. how to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use different event call for this(afteritemcollapse and afteritemexpand). Please refer below

```
afteritemcollapse( node, index, item, eOpts )
Fires after an item has been visually collapsed and is no longer visible in the tree. ...
Fires after an item has been visually collapsed and is no longer visible in the tree.
Available since: 4.1.0
Parameters
•node : Ext.data.NodeInterface
The node that was collapsed
•index : Number
The index of the node
•item : HTMLElement
The HTML element for the node that was collapsed
•eOpts : Object
The options object passed to Ext.util.Observable.addListener.
```

and for expand:

```
afteritemexpand( node, index, item, eOpts )
Fires after an item has been visually expanded and is visible in the tree. ...
Fires after an item has been visually expanded and is visible in the tree.
Available since: 4.1.0
Parameters
•node : Ext.data.NodeInterface
The node that was expanded
•index : Number
The index of the node
•item : HTMLElement
The HTML element for the node that was expanded
•eOpts : Object
The options object passed to Ext.util.Observable.addListener.
```

I hope this will help u.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks Hariharan. I was seeing how itemcollapse and itemexpand comes into play here. Because tree is already in expanded state, and I am trying to do a click event on the child on up/down arrow move.